# My list view is not showing anything i have use array adapter and no error in logcat

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

I am not getting anything in the listview when i am running this code.

I am trying to get value from server in text view,i am getting value from server in payload object.but still my list view is not showing anything and there is no error in logcat.

```
            import android.content.Context;
            import android.content.SharedPreferences;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
            import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
            import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
            import android.util.Log;
            import android.view.LayoutInflater;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.ViewGroup;
            import android.widget.AdapterView;
            import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.CheckBox;
            import android.widget.ListView;
            import android.widget.TextView;
            import android.widget.Toast;

            import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
            import com.android.volley.Request;
            import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
            import com.android.volley.Response;
            import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
            import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
            import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
            import com.zalonstyles.app.zalon.Model.Services;
            import com.zalonstyles.app.zalon.Model.ViewHolder;

            import org.json.JSONArray;
            import org.json.JSONException;
            import org.json.JSONObject;

            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.HashMap;
            import java.util.List;
            import java.util.Map;
```

This is the class where i am getting data from server

```
public  class popup_massage extends AppCompatActivity {
                public static final String URL =  "http://52.41.72.46:8080/service/get_category";
                public final String serviceid = "6";
                private ListView mainListView;
                private Button check;
                private List<Services> massagelist = new ArrayList<>();
                private Services massageservice[];
                private Context context;
               public ArrayAdapter<Services> listAdapter;


                @Override
                protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.popup_massage);
                    SharedPreferences mSharedPreference= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                    String value=(mSharedPreference.getString("AppConstant.AUTH_TOKEN", "DEFAULT"));
                    Log.e("accesslog",value);
                    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView4);
                    check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

                    final JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        params.put("service_id",serviceid);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        params.put("access_token", value);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                            new Response.Listener<String>(){

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {

                                    Log.v("updateUPVolleyRes1",response);

                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(response);
                                        JSONArray payload = jobject.getJSONArray("payload");
                                        Log.e("payloaddata", String.valueOf(payload));
                                        for (int i = 0; i < payload.length(); i++) {
                                            try{
                                                JSONObject obj = payload.getJSONObject(i);
                                                Services service = new Services();
                                                service.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                                service.setcategotry_id(obj.getString("id"));
                                                massagelist.add(service);







                                            }finally {

                                            }
                                        }
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }

                            }
                            , new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.v("updateUPVolleyErr", error.toString());

                        }
                    }){
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Map<String, String> params1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            params1.put("payload", params.toString());

                            Log.v("updateUPVolleyParams", params1.toString());

                            return params1;

                        }
                    };

                    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
                    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


                    mainListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item,
                                                        int position, long id)
                                {
                                    Services massageservice = listAdapter.getItem(position);
                                    Log.e("CHECKADAPTOR", String.valueOf(massageservice));
                                    massageservice.toggleChecked();
                                    ViewHolder viewHolder =(ViewHolder) item
                                            .getTag();
                                    viewHolder.getCheckBox().setChecked(massageservice.isChecked());
                                }
                            });
                    //Services[] massageService = (Services[]) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();ArrayList<Services> massagelist = new ArrayList<Services>();
                    //massagelist.addAll(Arrays.asList(massageService));

                    // Set our custom array adapter as the ListView's adapter.

                    listAdapter = new massageArrayAdapter(this,massagelist);

                    mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);



                    check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {


                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++)
                            {
                                Services massage = listAdapter.getItem(i);
                                if (massage.isChecked())
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            massage.getName() + " is Checked!!",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.v("My Custom Tag", massage.getName());

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    });


                }
        //arrayadapter class//

                private static class massageArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Services>
                {

                    private LayoutInflater inflater;

                    public massageArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Services> massagelist)
                    {
                        super(context, R.layout.customlist_massage, R.id.massagetextview, massagelist);
                        // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
                        inflater = LayoutInflater.from((Context) context);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
                    {
                        // services to display
                        Services massage = (Services) this.getItem(position);

                        // The child views in each row.
                        CheckBox checkBox;
                        TextView textView;

                        // Create a new row view
                        if (convertView == null)
                        {
                            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlist_massage,null );

                            // Find the child views.
                            textView = (TextView) convertView
                                    .findViewById(R.id.massagetextview);
                            checkBox = (CheckBox) `enter code here`convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);

                            // Optimization: Tag the row with it's child views, so we don't
                            // have to
                            // call findViewById() later when we reuse the row.
                            convertView.setTag(new ViewHolder(textView, checkBox));

                            // If CheckBox is toggled, update the planet it is tagged with.
                            checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                public void onClick(View v)
                                {
                                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                                    Services massage = (Services) cb.getTag();
                                    massage.setChecked(cb.isChecked());
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        // Reuse existing row view
                        else
                        {
                            // Because we use a ViewHolder, we avoid having to call
                            // findViewById().
                            ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView
                                    .getTag();
                            checkBox = viewHolder.getCheckBox();
                            textView = viewHolder.getTextView();
                        }

                        // Tag the CheckBox with the service it is displaying,       
                        // access the planet in onClick() when the CheckBox is     toggled.         
                        checkBox.setTag(massage);

                        // Display planet data
                        checkBox.setChecked(massage.isChecked());
                        textView.setText(massage.getName());

                        return convertView;
                    }

                }

            }
```

My Service class used to store services

```
  public class Services
      {
       private String name = "";
       private boolean checked = false;
       private String categotry_id="";

        public Services()
        {
        }

        public Services(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Services(String name, boolean checked,String categotry_id)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.categotry_id = categotry_id;
        this.checked = checked;
    }
        public Services(String name,String categotry_id)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.categotry_id = categotry_id;

        }
        public String getCategory_id(String id)
        {
            return categotry_id;
        }

        public void setcategotry_id(String categotry_id)
        {
            this.name = categotry_id;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public boolean isChecked()
        {
            return checked;
        }

        public void setChecked(boolean checked)
        {
            this.checked = checked;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public void toggleChecked()
        {
            checked = !checked;
        }
    }
```

View holder class for storing views

```
            public class ViewHolder
            {
                private CheckBox checkBox;
                private TextView textView;

                public ViewHolder()
                {
                }

                public ViewHolder(TextView textView, CheckBox checkBox)
                {
                    this.checkBox = checkBox;
                    this.textView = textView;
                }

                public CheckBox getCheckBox()
                {
                    return checkBox;
                }

                public void setCheckBox(CheckBox checkBox)
                {
                    this.checkBox = checkBox;
                }

                public TextView getTextView()
                {
                    return textView;
                }

                public void setTextView(TextView textView)
                {
                    this.textView = textView;
                }
            }
```

my xml class where list view is there

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3F51B5">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="313dp"
        android:text="Continue" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me through this I need to submit this by tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlist_massage,null ,false );
```

Instead this

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlist_massage,null );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are extending the adapter class ArrayAdapter.
If You want to show something on listview you have to extend it to BaseAdapter OR Recyclerview Adapter.
You dont have any getCount() method in ArrayAdapter see this example::

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater li;
    ArrayList<String> title, details;
    Context con;
    DataBaseHelper db;
    TextView txttitle, txtdetails, txtDate;
    Intent in;
    public static int i = 1;
    View view;

    public Adapter (Context cont, ArrayList<String> news_id, ArrayList<String> news) {
        this.title = news_id;
        this.details = news;
        this.con = cont;
        li = (LayoutInflater) con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        System.out.println("title.size() " + title.size());
        return title.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

        if (arg1 == null) {
            arg1 = li.inflate(R.layout.adapter_daycare, null);

            txttitle = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.title);
            txtdetails = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.details);
            txtDate = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.txtdate);
            view = (View) arg1.findViewById(R.id.view);


        }


        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date());

        System.out.println(" formattedDate " + date);


        txttitle.setText(title.get(arg0).toString());
        txtdetails.setText(details.get(arg0).toString());
        txtDate.setText(date);
        return arg1;

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you dont need to extend it to ArrayAdapter.See that example that will be clear enough.